# Has Granger causality been used successfully in a industrial liability case?

Tags: proof, granger-causality

Wikipedia claims that Granger causality is somewhat accepted as a way to prove event A caused event B. Has it ever been used to prove, for example, a company was responsible for industrial accident that contaminated an area of land? Would it be appropriate for this?

Comment: Could you explain how a theory about *time series* would be applied to a *singular event* like an accident?  I can imagine some creative ways, but am interested in what specifically you have in mind, so that we can know more precisely what you're asking here.

Comment: @whuber I was thinking that there would be a series of measurements over time that evidenced the contamination. At first there would be a hint of contamination, and then, as more measurements came in, analysts would be able to better pin down the source, the exact composition of the contamination. Then under warrant they ask for the operating details of factories in the area at the time. They use Granger causation to link the waste products of one of the factories and the composition given by the measurements. The measurements were from a sensor array in the rivers. All fictional, btw.

Comment: @whuber  I am interested in seeing how those claims of reliably predict causation have been tested / taken seriously in the real world. Law court is a just a way to measure how well it has been accepted as being able to 'support' causality.

Comment: In the US the court cannot allow an expert to create new methods for a case: to be allowed to testify, the expert must demonstrate that their methods are normal, accepted, and have been peer reviewed. Moreover, the courts do not pretend to be arbiters of science: they know the law, not all things! Therefore *nobody* uses the results of court cases to measure acceptance of statistical methods.

Comment: @whuber If Granger Causality had been used by courts successfully, that would mean that to at least a group of lawyers and judges it seemed a reasonable method of proving causality. For this to have happened, the belief in Granger Causality's effectiveness must have filtered through to these people, indicating that elsewhere, probably somewhere in science or industry, from a group of people likely closer to being able to accurately assess GC's effectiveness, GC has also been deemed effective. The spread of acceptance depends on how many groups propagate it, measuring deemed effectiveness.

Comment: @whuber Ideas that have been tested in the courts, have undergone intense competitive scrutiny, and are as you say, normal, accepted and peer reviewed enough to merit a kind of popular acknowledgement of utility that a court could be comfortable with, which is a relatively informative indication of (or sometimes prediction of succeeding) widespread acceptance. Evidence of these cases, and how it was used would be useful as a way to "sample" this popular acceptance, and get insight into how useful a tool this Granger Causality was deemed to be, from an additional perspective to academia.

Comment: In short...a way to cross validate.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Grainger is appropriate for concluding whether an event caused another but rather whether a time series caused another (using "caused" very loosely).

I don't know of any real litigation cases. But I could imagine something like a time-series of accidents in a factory and another of percent of hiring non union employees.

Maybe there's a correlation; but a question might arise: "Do more accidents happen after non-union employees are hired?" or "Do managers hire non-union employees in response to accidents?"

Not sure how valid / realistic this is; but that's my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks for those thoughts, especially related to workplace accidents. I could imagine GC being used as a tool, and am wondering if anyone knows of it being used.